# DraggableScrollableSheet doesn't give the current position of the sheet when dragging

Tags: flutter

In flutter we have a widget **DraggableScrollableSheet**. Now I want the current position or the current size of the child while it is dragging. There is currently no way to get that value. It gives a ScrollController in its builder method but that is for when the list is scrolling and not when its being dragged. So is there another way by which I can track the current drag position of the list?

I tried adding NotificationListener but that only gives me dragstartnofification and dragendnotification and nothing for dragupdate:

```
DraggableScrollableSheet(
          initialChildSize: .70,
          minChildSize: .70,
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollcontroller) {
            return NotificationListener(
              onNotification: (notification) {
                print("$notification");
              },
              child: Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    controller: scrollcontroller,
                    itemCount: widget.songs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return buildSongRow(widget.songs[index]);
                    }),
              ),
            );
          }),
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I found the solution to this. Flutter team updated the ScrollableDraggableSheet class in the Flutter v1.7.3. They added a class called DraggableScrollableNotification which you can listen to to get the current extend of the child when dragging.

```
NotificationListener<DraggableScrollableNotification>(
      onNotification: (notification) {

        print("${notification.extent}");
      },
      child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
          initialChildSize: .70,
          minChildSize: .70,
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollcontroller) {
            return Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: scrollcontroller,
                  itemCount: widget.songs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return buildSongRow(widget.songs[index]);
                  }),
            );
          }),
    )
```

in the above sample **notification.extent** will give you the current extent(position) of the child when dragging.

> Note: this is currently in the master channel and not in the stable
>   channel. Switch to the **master channel** by running  **flutter channel master**
>   and then **flutter upgrade** to make it work for now.

Comment: For convenience, to get a value drag value between 0.0 and 1.0, try this: `final dragRatio = (notification.extent - notification.minExtent) / (notification.maxExtent - notification.minExtent)`.