# It is possible to know the fraction of a DraggableScrollableSheet shown on the screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, draggable

I wonder if there is any possibility of knowing how much space the DraggableScrollableSheet is taking on the screen? I know that there are minChildSize and maxChildSize, so I suppose somewhere internal an actual fraction value is stored. Is there a way to listen to that value?

Comment: there is `ScrollController scrollController` passed to the `builder` - most likely it can be used for getting the current scroll offset

Comment: Unfortunately the scrollController is "active" just when the child is scrolled. But when the sheet is dragged it does nothing. Is there any way to know when and how much the sheet is dragged?

Comment: see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/f9c825981c/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/draggable_scrollable_sheet.dart#L178 - i did not try it but it seems you can catch that `Notification` with `NotificationListener`

Comment: Yeah! Thank you. I found here what i needed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56506540/draggablescrollablesheet-doesnt-give-the-current-position-of-the-sheet-when-dra - thank you for guidance

Comment: sure, your welcome, one advice: when not sure always take a look into the sources, just like i did - i did not know about `DraggableScrollableNotification` before but after 2 minutes of reading the sources i realized that it is dispatched during the drag

Comment: Thank you for advice! Surely I will follow it!

Comment: good luck then!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use NotificationListener and its method onNotification to know the current value of your DraggableScrollableSheet.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:payments/common/utils/colors.dart';
import 'package:payments/common/widgets/draggable_indicator.dart';

/// DraggableHistoryScreen class.
/// This class represents an screen for android and IOS
class DraggableHistoryScreen extends StatefulWidget{

  final double initialChildSize;

  /// Constructor method.
  DraggableHistoryScreen({
    required this.initialChildSize
  }); 

  @override
  _DraggableHistoryScreenState createState() => _DraggableHistoryScreenState();
}

/// _DraggableHistoryScreenState class.
/// This class represents the state for [DraggableHistoryScreen]
class _DraggableHistoryScreenState extends State<DraggableHistoryScreen>{
  

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: NotificationListener<DraggableScrollableNotification>(
          onNotification: (data) {
            //Here the data of your DraggableScrollableSheet
            print(data);
            return true;
          },
          child:  DraggableScrollableSheet(
            maxChildSize: 1.0,
            minChildSize: widget.initialChildSize,
            initialChildSize: widget.initialChildSize,
            builder: (context, scrollController) {
              return Stack(
                children: [
                  SingleChildScrollView(
                    controller: scrollController,
                    child: Container(
                        height:872.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0)),
                          color:AppColors.white_third_tone,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    child: DraggableIndicator())
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        )
      );
  }

}
```